# TypeScript variable is undefined although it has been defined

Tags: typescript, react-native

Hi I get a undefined termsAndConditionsMetricFinal error if i use following code snippet:

```
 const TermsAndConditionsMetricPre: Record<string, any> = Object.entries(
      onboardingStateUserMetadata.TermsAndConditionsList,
    ).map((entry) => {
      var termsAndConditionsMetricFinalArray = TermsAndConditionsMetricFinalArray;
      var termsAndConditionsMetricFinal = TermsAndConditionsMetricFinal;
      const [key, value] = entry;
      if (typeof value !== 'number') {
        console.log(value);
        console.log(termsAndConditionsMetricFinal);
        termsAndConditionsMetricFinal.answer = value;
        termsAndConditionsMetricFinal.question = key;
        termsAndConditionsMetricFinal.class = 'TermsAndCondition';
      }
      termsAndConditionsMetricFinal.parameterValue = value;
      termsAndConditionsMetricFinal.question = key;
      termsAndConditionsMetricFinal.class = 'TermsAndCondition';
      termsAndConditionsMetricFinalArray.push(termsAndConditionsMetricFinal);
      return { key, value };
    });
```

I try to save information from one list into a another with different properties

Comment: Can u please share the error stack trace?

Comment: We will need to see the contents of `onboardingStateUserMetadata.TermsAndConditionsList` to be able to assess the issue

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).